# Downloading the SubSonic Starter Kit

Tags: subsonic, starter-kits

Here's an easy one for you... perhaps.  The SubSonic Starter Kit that is discussed on the SubSonicProject Site, is MIA.  All links to DL it point to the now defunct CodePlex project.  There appears to be no such DL on the Google Project Site.  10 bucks to the first person who can tell be where I can get the bits.  Well, maybe not 10 bucks, but I will vote you up.

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/subsoniccms/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

LOL The starter site is mighty old :) but it's in the installer when you download SubSonic. Just have a peak in there and it should be part of the file set.

I also have a nice MVC site that is quite nice if you can chill for another week or so..

Comment: How's that MVC site coming along?